# LMD on Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: scanner, malware, clamav

Despite haviing ClamAV-Daemon installed, LMD / inotify always execute `usr/bin/clamscan` for scans, rather than using clamd, causes 100% CPU usage spikes.

I've checked the `/usr/local/maletect/conf.maldet` and I cannot find a setting to change which scanner LMD/inotify utilizes for scans?

I have already place `CPUQuota` and MemoryHigh`values on`/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service`, but the settings are ignored by`  /usr/bin/clamscan`.

How might I choose LMD's scanner and/or limit `usr/bin/clamscan`  cpu/memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

After testing & reading... it seems using clamdscan over clamscan was an unattainable dream.  So, my solution to finally put `/usr/bin/clamscan` on a leash was to limit the cpu limit usage via a cpulimit command:

`#crontab -e`  add
`@reboot cpulimit -P /usr/bin/clamscan -l 20`

and to edit the clamv-daemon as follows:

`#nano /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d/extend.conf`

```
root@admin:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d/extend.conf
[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir -p /run/clamav
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown clamav /run/clamav
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=64M
IOSchedulingPriority = 7 
CPUSchedulingPolicy = 5 
MemoryLimit=128M 
CPUQuota=30%
Nice = 19
#
```

And, `/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service` the same as above.

**WARNING**: NEVER use MemoryMax= with clamav because it will simply kill clamav and prevent it from actually scanning for viruses.